# How to send ctrl+d in Expect/Tcl?

Tags: tcl, expect

The following hangs after sending `foo\r` (`ctrl+d` is not triggered).

**Edit:** somehow, replacing `\x04` by `\x04\x04` works. Not sure why control character has to be sent twice…

```
expect {
  -re {Type foo and press enter, then ctrl\+d} {
    send "foo\r\x04"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @glennjackman I was under the impression that my answer worked, but after more debugging noticed that it didn't... so I updated question instead hoping someone could help.

Comment: It should work. Perhaps your spawned application is doing something like an ioctl to change the tty mode from *canonical*, or flush input. Try `send "foo\r";sleep 1;send "\x04"` to check.

Comment: @meuh Interesting! Using `sleep 1` worked.